# Dojo query to find all descendants by class name

Tags: javascript, dojo, children

Given a DOM node, I want to drill down the DOM tree to find any nodes by a given class name, say `myClass`

For example

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="red">Red One</div>
  Some Text
    <div>
        <div class="myClass"></div>
    </div>
  <div class="blue">Blue One</div>
  <div class="red">Red Two</div>
  <div class="blue">Blue Two</div>
</div>
```

I have tried using `dojo.query(".container").children(".myClass");` which doesnt seem to get a handle on it.

I noticed `dojo.query(".container").children();` will only fetch the immediate children, is there an easy way to get all descendants, grandchildren if you will, and not just immediate children?

**EDIT**

so I realise the question isn't exactly as I had planned, but I will keep the original in place to allow for other users that might benefit from it.

My issue is that rather than getting a handle on the first node by the class name, I want to assume I have got a handle on a particular set of nodes with that class name, but maybe not all of them.

So for example what I would have liked to use, to keep in line with what is written above, would be,

```
array.forEach(containerNodes, function(node){
    dojo.query(node).children(".myClass")
});
```

if only the `children()` function traversed more than one tree level.

So for this scenario, I used `dojo.query(".myClass", node);` which worked.

But as mentioned below, the likes of `dojo.query(".container .myClass");` will work for using class names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`children()` is just like in jQuery, where it only gives you immediate children. If you want to create a "subquery" (like jQuery's `find()`), you will have to use [`query()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojo/query#1_9dojo_NodeList_query), for example:

```
dojo.query(".container").query(".myClass");
```

I also made a [small fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xgc9/) demonstrating it (however, it's in Dojo 1.9 syntax).

Comment: Thanks, I also got this working by `dojo.query(".myClass",containerNode)`

Comment: Yeah, that will work as well, but it kind of breaks the entire chaining purpose that the `dojo/query` module provides. You could also do something like `dojo.query(".container .myClass");`.

Comment: emm, your right but Im at fault in that I have realised, based on your answer, that I haven't described the question slightly wrong. I will amend the question