# Is there any way to use Dojo/query to grab classname with a specific number instead of getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, dojo

I wanted to change document.getElementsByClassName to dojo.query or query but wont' work:

```
var name =  document.getElementsByClassName("dijitReset dijitInputInner")[1];
```

this one works

```
var name  = dojo.query(".dijitReset dijitInputInner")[1];
```

this one won't work

Comment: Pro tip: you can [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your code with code fences or indent 4 spaces

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750927/dojo-query-to-find-all-descendants-by-class-name

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.query` returns an array-like NodeList, and `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like HTMLCollection. The problem is not with that, but with your selectors.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("dijitReset dijitInputInner")
```

will select elements with either the class `dijitReset` or the class `dijitInputInner`.

`dojo.query(".dijitReset dijitInputInner")`

will select elements with a *tag name* of `dijitInputInner` that are descendants from an element with a class name containing `dijitReset`.

You need to change it to:

`dojo.query(".dijitReset, .dijitInputInner")`

with the comma (to indicate a new selector) and a `.` (to indicate a search for class).